# Как зафиксировать AppBarLayout в свёрнутом положении

Tags: android, material-design, coordinator-layout

Имеется CoordinatorLayout с вложенным в него AppBarLayout внутри CollapsingToolbarLayout а внутри него toolbar + картинка. Под AppBar находится ViewPager с вложенными фрагментами. ViewPager имеет поведение: `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`. И соответственно при прокрутке содержимого фрагментов appbar сворачивается.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavViewCoreAct"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                style="@style/AppBarLayoutSchool"
                android:id="@+id/appBarCoreAct">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    style="@style/CollapsingToolbar"
                    android:id="@+id/collapsToolbarCoreAct"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse"
                    app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/london_flat"
                        android:tint="@color/colorWhiteAlfa"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/service_image_item"
                        android:id="@+id/imgToolbarCoreAct"/>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        style="@style/Toolbar"
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarCoreAct"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerCore"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appBarCoreAct"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Однако в одном из фрагментов мне необходимо свернуть AppBar и зафиксировать его в таком положении.

```
val appBarCoreAct = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appBarCoreAct)
appBarCoreAct.setExpanded(false)
```

Код выше просто сворачивает toolbar но он продолжает разворачиваться. Если же установить флаг для `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
(collapsToolbarCoreAct.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams).scrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP
```

То изображение будет полного размера (примерно на пол экрана). Пробовал при установке флагов изменять размер изображения и делать его невидимым, но в таком случае пропадает title для `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Подскажите как свернуть AppBarLayout и запретить его разворачивание при прокрутке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог [ответ kris larson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324653/want-to-lock-appbarlayout-for-some-fragments) из поста англоязычного stack. Для моего случая, во время перехода на целевой фрагмент сделал следующее:

```
/*разворачиваем toolbar, чтоб изображение view pager не убегало за пределы экрана*/
appBarCoreAct.setExpanded(true) 
collapsToolbarCoreAct.visibility = View.GONE //прячем toolbar
```

...
Получаем искомый отображаемый в данный момент на экране фрагмент и устанавливаем для него `pageFragment.view?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false` готово

Однако появляется небольшая проблема. Так как nestedScroll отключен, если на фрагменте есть список то последний элемент не будет помещаться на экране ровно на столько, сколько места занимает toolbar. Можно решить эту проблему - проставив отступ.